# How to change windows security features to allow cygwin to interact with the desktop

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I would like to run a process on a remote machine in interactive way, I mean that even though it doesn't require any user interaction I need that the process pops up a window GUI.

I Use Cygwin 1.7 and I am able to start the process with `cygstart` but I don't know how to show its GUI. I use this command: 
`cygstart --show --action=runas COMMAND`

Moreover, I use my domain account - on the local and remote machine - and I noted on the Windows Task Manager that the process as User Name has my account but with a different Session ID.

---

The problem is related to Windows security default settings, and to accomplish that it should be possible - the question is how - to modify the Cygwin service `sshd` to "allow service to interact with desktop" or re-install `sshd` with `cygrunsrv` with `--interactive` flag.

---

Cygwin service `sshd` won't start if it has `--interactive` flag. After many endeavors I am still in the dark.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. You have ssh in a tag but nowhere in your question. If you mean what I think you mean based on your title and ssh tag, I wonder if some combination of SSH(which exists in cygwin) and psexec does it   Though I doubt it.  My guess is that SSH locks you into a command line. But there is an SSH with forwarding but it applies more to linux and  I think even that, isn't quite launching remote applications, I think with that (maybe ssh -X) they launch locally or show locally, in some way..

Comment: I discovered that the problem is related to Windows security default settings, and to accomplish that I should modify the Cygwin service to "allow service to interact with desktop".

Comment: Then add that as an answer

Comment: The unique way that I have found to run a process on a remote machine in interactive way is with PsExec, it seems not possible to do the same with Cygwin.